# Floating Button Not Taking Background Color

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, xml-drawable

I have a floating button in my main activity which is taking a color from my app theme colorAccent settings. And I want to change it. So I set the background color to a vector image which is a round circle. However, it is not taking effect. how can I force it to take effect to colorPrimaryDark which is green.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MyToolbarStyle">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_next_button"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

round_button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="50dp" android:width="50dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

For icon :

```
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
```

For background color :

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        ...
        app:backgroundTint="@color/yourcolor"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
     />
```